# How can I obtain a Blue Card in Spain?

Tags: europe, spain, residency, working-visas, blue-card

I'm living and working in Spain with the Work permit and my visa is multiple (Type-D).
I want to have a Blue Card as well.
I've searched a lot but couldn't find the process on the internet.

1. I want to know the exact process of obtaining the Blue Card.
2. Can I work in other European countries with that Blue Card which issued in Spain? (I've heard it should pass ~18 months before can work in other European countries)
3. Can I ask for permanent residency of a country(which ones?) after a certain period of time? (I've heard something about 5 years, and not all of the countries giving PR only by having the Blue Card) .
4. What are the other important benefits of having the Blue Card?

**Update(from comment):**
I fulfil the requirements of the Blue Card. My main question is where should I go to do that(In Spain)? And can I apply it directly by myself or my I have to talk with my company to help me(fill some documents) with this?

Comment: try 'spain blue card' and you find tons of answers to your questions. Any questions that are then left over should then be asked here.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I did: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=spain+blue+card and there is only 7 unrelated questions without an answer.

Comment: Google Search is where a great amount of information is to be found, remembering that only the official sites are reliable.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Believe me, I did, but there is only one PDF http://extranjeros.mitramiss.gob.es/es/InformacionInteres/FolletosInformativos/archivos/triptico_tarjeta_azul_eng.pdf which considers work permit and blue card the same as each other.

Comment: @Dr.jacky Have you looked at eg https://www.eu-bluecard.com/who-can-apply/

Comment: @Traveller Yes, and I fulfil the requirements. My main question is where should I go to do that(In Spain)? And can I apply it directly by myself or my I have to talk with my company to help me(fill some documents) with this.

Comment: @Dr.jacky, Then edit this and make that your specific question, with an explanation of your background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are documents(in Spanish, of course!) I've got from gov. lawyer.
Hope it helps someone:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]